After nodetool refresh number of records in the source is much larger than in the target instance
Restore snapshots to another cluster (migration)
source:
Scylla v. 4.4.1 on Kubernetes,
4 nodes  e.g. a1,a2,a3,a4
target:
Scylla v. 5.4.6 - no Kubernetes installation
4  nodes  e.g. b1,b2,b3,b4
Steps:

we built a cluster with the same number of nodes
the number of tokens is the same on the source and on the new installation
we took a snapshot of the table in nodetool
create the table manually (on new Scylla)
we copied the snapshot to the new Scylla to the upload directory:
snapshot from a1->b1, a2->b2, a3->b3, a4->b4
then on each node:
nodetool refresh keyspace_name table_name -las
nodetool cleanup keyspace_name

and... the number of records in the source is much larger than in the target instance.
Where is the mistake?
